# Craft 3 to webserver (with only access to public_html )

Tags: deployment

I just wanted to deploy, my site live, but I was running to some issues.
I read that I should put only the web folder to public_html and all the other folders and files above that.

But on my server provider I have only access to the public_html folder itself, and I cannot go above that.

I found this guide: https://craftcms.com/guides/moving-craft-files , but when I apply this, I myself wont have access to the folder, so I cannot open the admin dashboard.

Is there a way to set an exception for myself, or I am doing something completely wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out, I wasnt keeping my web folder in the root, that was the problem.